# Im losing my mind with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I want the objects of this class:

```
public class Chromosome implements Runnable, Comparable<Chromosome> {
    private String[] chromosome;
    public double fitness;
    private Random chromoGen;

    public Chromosome(double[] candidate) {
        super();
        //encode candidate PER parameter; using Matrix as storage
        chromosome = encode(candidate);
        chromoGen = new Random();
    }

    //De-fault
    public Chromosome() {
        super();
        chromoGen = new Random();

        //de-fault genotype
        chromosome = new String[6];
    }

    /**
     * IMPLEMENTED
     */
    public void run() {
        //I hope leaving it empty works...
    }

    public int compareTo(Chromosome c) {
        return (int) (fitness - c.fitness);
    }

    /**
     * Fitness stored in chromosome!
     */
    public void setFitness(ArrayList<double[]> target) {
        fitness = FF.fitness(this, target);
    }

    public double getFitness() {
        return fitness;
    }

    /**
     * ENCODERS/DECODERS
     */
    public String[] encode(double[] solution) {
        //subtract 2^n from solution until you reach 2^-n

        /**
         * LENGTH: 51 BITS!!
         *
         * 1st BIT IS NEGATIVE/POSITIVE
         *
         * THE PRECISION IS [2^30 <-> 2^-20]!!!
         *
         * RANGE: -2.14748...*10^9 <-> 2.14748...*10^9
         */
        String[] encoded = new String[6];

        //PER PARAMETER
        for (int j = 0; (j < 6); j++) {
            encoded[j] = encode(solution[j]);
        }

        return encoded;
    }

    public String encode(double sol) {
        /**
         * THE PRECISION IS [2^30 <-> 2^-20]!!!
         */
        double temp = sol;
        String row = "";
        //NEGATIVITY CHECK
        if (temp < 0) {
            //negative
            row = "1";
        } else {
            //positive
            row = "0";
        }
        //main seq.
        for (int n = 30; (n > (-21)); n--) {
            if ((temp - Math.pow(2, n)) >= 0) {
                temp = temp - Math.pow(2, n);
                row = row + "1";
            } else {
                row = row + "0";
            }
        }
        return row;
    }

    public double decoded(int position) {
        //returns UN-ENCODED solution
        double decoded = 0.00;
        char[] encoded = (chromosome[position]).toCharArray();
        /**
         * [n?][<--int:30-->][.][<--ratio:20-->]
         */
        int n = 30;
        for (int i = 1; (i < encoded.length); i++) {
            if (encoded[i] == '1') {
                decoded += Math.pow(2, n);
            }
            //next binary-place
            n--;
        }
        //NEGATIVE??
        if (encoded[0] == '1') {
            decoded = ((-1) * decoded);
        }
        //Output
        return decoded;
    }

    /**
     * GETTERS
     * ---------------\/--REDUNDANT!!
     */
    public double getParameter(int parameter) {
        //decoded solution
        return decoded(parameter);
    }

    /**
     * Used in E-algrm.
     */
    public String getRow(int row) {
        //encoded solution
        return chromosome[row];
    }

    /**
     * SETTERS
     */
    public void setRow(String encoded, int row) {
        chromosome[row] = encoded;
    }

    public void setRow(double decoded, int row) {
        chromosome[row] = encode(decoded);
    }

    /**
     * MUTATIONS
     */
    public void mutate(double mutationRate) {
        //range of: 51
        double ran = 0;
        int r;
        char[] temp;
        for (int m = 0; (m < 6); m++) {
            temp = (chromosome[m]).toCharArray();
            ran = chromoGen.nextDouble();
            if (ran <= mutationRate) {
                r = chromoGen.nextInt(51);
                if (temp[r] == '1') {
                    temp[r] = '0';
                } else {
                    temp[r] = '1';
                }
            }
            //output
            chromosome[m] = new String(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

...To be in SEPARATE threads; however I have no need for the method `run()`; but when I try to do this:

```
child1 = new Chromosome();
(new Thread(child1)).start();
```

Still, the only thread I see at run-time is `main()`.
So, how can I make it separate threads??

Comment: The context is a linear evolutionary algorithm by the way.

Comment: The thread ends pretty fast since you don't have any code in it. Are you sure you're not missing it?

Comment: `run` is method that is called by `start` when the Thread becomes active

Comment: Do you want each object to run a separate thread?

Comment: Try putting an infinite loop in `run()` to see what it does.

Comment: You need the `run()` method because it defines what the runnable / thread should actually _do_.

Comment: It would appear that you think that a thread is something one can't do without. What do you expect from a thread, why do you think you need to use it? Unless you have a good answer for this, don't even think of using Runnable, run, Thread and so on.

Comment: You probably should work your way through the Java Concurrency tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see there is a problem in your understanding of how threads work.

When you create a thread, it looks for the method `run()`. There are several ways of creating threads. I am doing it by passing a `Runnable` object.

`Thread t=new Thread (new Runnable);`

Do you know how long a thread lives?

- A thread lives as long as the method `run()` exists and runs. A thread executes only the code inside the `run()` method. It is not designed to execute anything outside `run()`. The thread dies when the control moves out of `run()`.

Your case:

You left the `run()` method empty. So the thread executes nothing and dies as and when it is created.

What can you do?

Enclose the rest of the program in `run()` so that `run()` remains on the heap and therefore, the newly created thread runs the program.

You don't need to put everthing into `run()`, you can simply shift the first method call to `run()` so that it remains on the heap.

Let us take an example:

```
public class threading implements Runnable
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
       Thread t = new Thread (new Runnable);
        t.setName("thread1");
        t.start();
         print1();
         print2();

     }    
      public static void print2()
      {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
       }
       public static void print1()
      {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
       }
       public void run()
       {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
       }
}
```

Ouputs:

- thread1
- main
- main

Time to keep your new thread alive till the end.

```
public class threading implements Runnable
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
       Thread t = new Thread (new Runnable);
        t.setName("thread1");
        t.start();


     }    
      public static void print2()
      {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
       }
       public static void print1()
      {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
       print2();
       }
       public void run()
       {
      System.out.println(Thread.getName());
        print1();
       }
}
```

Output:

- thread1
- thread1
- thread1

We kept the method `run()` on the heap by putting a method call in `run()`. This method is the one which further maintains the flow.

Comment: Erm, so for a NON-static example replace main with the constructor??

Comment: I need Threads to allow a concurrent implementation of my simulation.

Comment: For non-static methods, you will have to create an object in main and use it to call the methods.

Comment: You are creating a new thread and you want the rest of your program to run in the new thread. right?

Comment: 1-thread-per-chromosome + the main()-thread which will contain the simulator.

Comment: What methods are executed by the chromosome?...put that method call in run().

Comment: Take a look at how I have placed a method call in run().

Comment: Other objects' call chromosomes' methods and all chromosomes'-methods are executed by itself.

Comment: Can I put the constructor in run()?? Will that work??

Comment: So you must decide the flow. You son't really need to force a new thread to run some part of the program. Anyways, only one thread runs at a time and I think, multiple threads wouldn't make a difference in your program.

Comment: You cannot put the constructor in `run()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Thread.start(), the new Thread will begin by execution of run() method, you should write what the thread has to do in run() method, after Thread finishes the run() method then it terminates, so it is no longer running or visible.

When you have empty run() method then it finishes instantly as is has nothing to do.
What the thread should do, what should be invoked? just put that invocation into run() method.

Try this, maybe it will work as you expect, but i'm just guessing that you would like to move what you process in constructor into a thread.

```
public class Chromosome implements Runnable, Comparable<Chromosome>
{
private String[] chromosome;
public double fitness;
private Random chromoGen;
private double[] candidate;


public Chromosome(double[] candidate)
{        
    super();
    this.candidate=candidate;

}
//De-fault
public Chromosome()
{
    super();

}

/**
 * IMPLEMENTED
 */
public void run()
{
    if (candidate!=null) {
        //encode candidate PER parameter; using Matrix as storage
        chromosome = encode(candidate);
        chromoGen = new Random();
    } else {

        chromoGen = new Random();

        //de-fault genotype
        chromosome = new String[6];
    }
}


public int compareTo(Chromosome c)
{
    return (int)(fitness - c.fitness);
}

/**
 * Fitness stored in chromosome!
 */
public void setFitness(ArrayList<double[]> target)
{
    fitness = FF.fitness(this, target);
}

public double getFitness()
{
    return fitness;
}

/**
 * ENCODERS/DECODERS
 */
public String[] encode(double[] solution)
{
    //subtract 2^n from solution until you reach 2^-n

    /**
     * LENGTH: 51 BITS!!
     * 
     * 1st BIT IS NEGATIVE/POSITIVE
     * 
     * THE PRECISION IS [2^30 <-> 2^-20]!!!
     * 
     * RANGE: -2.14748...*10^9 <-> 2.14748...*10^9
     */
    String[] encoded = new String[6];

    //PER PARAMETER
    for (int j = 0; (j < 6); j++){
        encoded[j] = encode(solution[j]);
    }

    return encoded;
}

public String encode(double sol)
{
    /**
     * THE PRECISION IS [2^30 <-> 2^-20]!!!
     */
    double temp = sol;
    String row = "";
    //NEGATIVITY CHECK
    if (temp < 0){
        //negative
        row = "1";
    }
    else{
        //positive
        row = "0";
    }
    //main seq.
    for (int n = 30; (n > (-21)); n--){
        if ((temp - Math.pow(2, n)) >= 0){
            temp = temp - Math.pow(2, n);
            row = row+"1";
        }
        else{
            row = row+"0";
        }
    }
    return row;
}

public double decoded(int position)
{
    //returns UN-ENCODED solution
    double decoded = 0.00;
    char[] encoded = (chromosome[position]).toCharArray();
    /**
     * [n?][<--int:30-->][.][<--ratio:20-->]
     */
    int n = 30;
    for (int i = 1; (i < encoded.length); i++){
        if (encoded[i] == '1'){
            decoded += Math.pow(2, n);
        }
        //next binary-place
        n--;
    }
    //NEGATIVE??
    if (encoded[0] == '1'){
        decoded = ((-1)*decoded);
    }
    //Output
    return decoded;
}

/**
 * GETTERS
 * ---------------\/--REDUNDANT!!
 */
public double getParameter(int parameter)
{
    //decoded solution
    return decoded(parameter);
}

/**
 * Used in E-algrm.
 */
public String getRow(int row)
{
    //encoded solution
    return chromosome[row];
}

/**
 * SETTERS
 */
public void setRow(String encoded, int row)
{
    chromosome[row] = encoded;
}

public void setRow(double decoded, int row)
{
    chromosome[row] = encode(decoded);
}

/**
 * MUTATIONS
 */
public void mutate(double mutationRate)
{
    //range of: 51
    double ran = 0;
    int r;
    char[] temp;
    for (int m = 0; (m < 6); m++){
        temp = (chromosome[m]).toCharArray();
        ran = chromoGen.nextDouble();
        if (ran <= mutationRate){
            r = chromoGen.nextInt(51);
            if (temp[r] == '1'){
                temp[r] = '0';
            }
            else{
                temp[r] = '1';
            }
        }
        //output
        chromosome[m] = new String(temp);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your thread fine and must work, but your `run` method is empty and the thread get terminated without you noticing it

Try this:

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("I hope leaving it empty works...");
}
```

and if you see the Message in the `console`, then everything is fine and you need only to add a condition/loop/logic inside the `run` method so that is not getting terminated before you do the work done.